# any tip to improve performance when using nested loops with python

Tags: python, performance, nested-loops

so, I had this exercise where I would receive a list of integers and had to find how many sum pairs were multiple to 60

example:

input: `list01 = [10,90,50,40,30]`

result = 2

explanation: 10 + 50, 90 + 30

example2:

input: `list02 = [60,60,60]`

result = 3

explanation: `list02[0] + list02[1], list02[0] + list02[2], list02[1] + list02[2]`

seems pretty easy, so here is my code:

```
def getPairCount(numbers):
    total = 0
    cont = 0
    for n in numbers:
        cont+=1
        for n2 in numbers[cont:]:
            if (n + n2) % 60 == 0:
                total += 1
    return total
```

it's working, however, for a big input with over 100k+ numbers is taking too long to run, and I need to be able to run in under 8 seconds, any tips on how to solve this issue??

being with another lib that i'm unaware or being able to solve this without a nested loop

Comment: See [**`itertools.combinations`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: It is very interesting task. You can read an idea of this task here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-in-array-whose-sum-is-divisible-by-k/

Comment: Additionally, you could use Numpy to speed up the "hash"-based code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that should be extremely fast (it runs in O(n) time).  It makes use of the following observation:  We only care about each value mod 60.  E.g. 23 and 143 are effectively the same.

So rather than making an O(n**2) nested pass over the list, we instead count how many of each value we have, mod 60, so each value we count is in the range 0 - 59.

Once we have the counts, we can consider the pairs that sum to 0 or 60.  The pairs that work are:

```
0 + 0
1 + 59
2 + 58
...
29 + 31
30 + 30
```

After this, the order is reversed, but we only
want to count each pair once.

There are two cases where the values are the same:
0 + 0 and 30 + 30.  For each of these, the number
of pairs is `(count * (count - 1)) // 2`.  Note that
this works when count is 0 or 1, since in both cases
we're multiplying by zero.

If the two values are different, then the number of
cases is simply the product of their counts.

Here's the code:

```
def getPairCount(numbers):
    # Count how many of each value we have, mod 60

    count_list = [0] * 60
    for n in numbers:
        n2 = n % 60
        count_list[n2] += 1

    # Now find the total

    total = 0

    c0 = count_list[0]
    c30 = count_list[30]

    total += (c0 * (c0 - 1)) // 2
    total += (c30 * (c30 - 1)) // 2

    for i in range(1, 30):
        j = 60 - i
        total += count_list[i] * count_list[j]

    return total
```

This runs in O(n) time, due to the initial one-time pass we make over the list of input values.  The loop at the end is just iterating from 1 through 29 and isn't nested, so it should run almost instantly.

Comment: this solution is amazing, thx, I just saw that I still have a lot to improve regarding my algorithms

Comment: @RaulQuinzani A lot of programming puzzles involve obtaining a result mod some value.  In those cases, it often helps to ask yourself how early you can apply the mod operator to simplify the problem.

Comment: I think you can throw some numpy in the mix for even better performances. `count_list = np.zeros(60, dtype=int); for n in (np.array(numbers)%60): count_list[n] += 1` and at the end: `total += np.dot(count_list[1:30:+1], count_list[59:30:-1])`. (Added as a new comment since I messed up the indexes and could not edit after 5 minutes)

Comment: @Guimoute Thanks.  It's an interesting idea.  The runtime of the algorithm is dominated by the loop that does the `% 60` operation and saves the counts, so it's a question of whether the overhead of converting the input list to a numpy array would be made up for by performing the `%` operation directly on the numpy array.  That would only be possible if the numpy code were written in C rather than Python.  It would be interesting to do a timing comparison to see if there's any speed improvement.

Comment: @Guimoute Actually, perhaps the biggest problem with the numpy version is it would change the memory usage of the algorithm from O(1) to O(n), since it's copying the entire input array, so that alone would probably result in a slower run time.  Converting it to numpy would make more sense if it were being used multiple times for some compute-intensive linear algebra operations.

Comment: I have tested it yesterday and it's indeed taking longer with the numpy version. I just hope OP already uses a numpy array (as they mentioned 100k values) so that we can skip the conversion.

Comment: @Guimoute There's no numpy array involved. This was a coding exercise. It wouldn't have made sense to use numpy unless there was a *significant* performance improvement.

Comment: @TomKarzes I understand it's an exercise, but in a real situation we could imagine that data coming from a `.h5` file, a spreadsheet, etc. in which case numpy or pandas will be recommended to read  the file quickly, then the input is available as a numpy.ndarray "for free".

Answer (score 0):

Below is a translation of Tom Karzes's answer but using numpy. I benchmarked it and it is only faster if the input is already a numpy array, not a list. I still want to write it here because it nicely shows how loops in python can be one-liners in numpy.

```
def get_pairs_count(numbers, /):

    # Count how many of each value we have, modulo 60.
    numbers_mod60 = np.mod(numbers, 60)
    _, counts = np.unique(numbers_mod60, return_counts=True)

    # Now find the total.
    total = 0   
    c0 = counts[0]
    c30 = counts[30]
    total += (c0 * (c0 - 1)) // 2
    total += (c30 * (c30 - 1)) // 2
    total += np.dot(counts[1:30:+1], counts[59:30:-1]) # Notice the slicing indices used.
    return total
```